# Typescript - can't access properties in child class via Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the same logic declared in constructor of base class for all child classes.
In more details, I want to iterate over all class attributes from it's constructor.

My expectation was that if I invoke Object.keys() in base constructor and call super() in child's constructor - it will work for me.

Code example:

```
class BaseClass {
    private baseField1: string;
    private baseField2: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        console.log(this.constructor.name + " has fields: " + Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private childField1: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        super(data);
    }
}

let base = new ChildClass({name: 'Joe'});
```

I expect to have output:
**ChildClass has fields: baseField1,baseField2,childField1**

But in fact I have:
**ChildClass has fields: baseField1,baseField2**

There is no childField1 in output

Any idea on how this is better to sort out?

**UPD:**

Finally I made it work as I expect. Thanks to Touffy!

```js
class BaseClass {
    private baseField1: string;
    private baseField2: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private childField1: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        super(data);
        if (data.childField1) this.childField1 = data.childField1;
    }
}

let base = new ChildClass({
    baseField1: 'bf1',
    baseFileds2: 'bf2', 
    childField1: 'Joe'
});

console.log('Class fields: ' + JSON.stringify(base));
```

Output is: **Class fields: {"baseField1":"bf1","baseFileds2":"bf2","childField1":"Joe"}**

Comment: What is the actual goal here?

Comment: The goal is to have common logic to iterate over all properties in child classes. Logic should not depend on properties names and properties count

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the properties in the children classes? Each child class should implement a different behaviour that, most of the times, depend on properties specific to that class. This is why children classes are created: to not mix unrelated behaviours in a single function/class.

Comment: The posted code does not expose the behaviour described in the question because the properties are not initialized. Depending on how they are initialized, the code might have or might not have the described behaviour.

Comment: Seems, I am still expecting it to work as Java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with `Object.keys`, but the timing of when it is called in the constructor chain. You wrote the call of `Object.keys` in the parent constructor, which is called by `super` in the child constructor *before any child properties are initialized*.

You need to remember that those nice property declarations are merely syntactic sugar, equivalent to `this.propertyName = undefined` in the constructor. Those lines are evaluated *after* the call to `super` (the parent constructor). In other words, what the JavaScript interpreter will really do is this :

```js
class BaseClass {
    constructor(data) {
        this.baseField1 = undefined;
        this.baseField2 = undefined
        console.log(this.constructor.name + " has fields: " + Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(data) {
        BaseClass.call(this, data);
        this.childField1 = undefined // too late !
    }
}
```

If you call `Object.keys` in the child constructor *after* `super()`, or anywhere that's not in a constructor, it will work as expected.

However, if your goal is specifically to log all the properties of a child instance **immediately when it is constructed**, **and have this behaviour inherited from the parent class**… I don't think you can, even with Proxies.

Comment: I was trying to have all the logic in parent constructor, so I could iterate all the properties using the same logic which is not depend on properties names and it's count.

It makes no sense to write Object.keys in each child's constructor given that it could be 100 childs..

Comment: What you're asking for is runtime introspection on class types. JavaScript doesn't have class types. You can only look at things you have actually instantiated. Best you could do, IMO, would be a method on the parent class, that you call on the child *after* construction : e.g. `let base = new ChildClass('Joe'); base.inspectProps();`

Answer (score -1):

`constructor(data: any)` -- this is not OOP, this is bad JavaScript habits under disguise.

Be as specific as possible with the interface of your class. Let it ask exactly what values it needs in the constructor, not just some opaque object.

```js
class BaseClass {
  public constructor(
    private baseField1: string,
    private baseField2: string,
  ) {
    // Object.keys(this) is not a good idea if the class has methods
    console.log(this.constructor.name + " has fields: " + Object.keys(this));
  }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  public constructor(
    baseField1: string,
    baseField2: string,
    private childField1: string;
  ){
    super(baseField1, baseField2);
  }
}

// The compiler does not allow you to pass only one argument to the constructor
// It ensures the object integrity
let base = new ChildClass('Joe');
```

Comment: A good guideline — if a little opinionated —, but how does this answer the question ? shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: The question asks how to keep writing promiscuous code. The answer is: don't do it. It is easy to say "stop doing this" but without an alternative, it is worth nothing. My answer probably does not help the OP because they want to keep doing whatever they are doing now in their code but it's the best advice I can provide having the limited amount of information provided in the question.

Comment: The question was not about having parameter in constructor at all.
I was asking about base - parent class related things, so I found you answer not related to initial question

Comment: @Sergei What was the initial question about? The code does not do what you describe. Or it does, depends how you fill the missing pieces.